# Is there an issue in spring's guide?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Following spring's guide [Centralized configuration](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/) 
today (27 January 2017), the spring-boot application crash at startup with 
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener`

I think the reason is that the dependency management's BOM refers to spring-cloud-starter-parent in version **Angel.SR4** while the parent project is spring-boot-starter-parent in version **1.4.3.RELEASE**.

Angel.SR4 is quite old and still refers to old version of Spring-Boot which conflicts with spring-boot-starter-parent's version.

replacing **Angel.SR4** with **Camden.SR4** fixed the issue.

Is there something i've missed or is it a issue on spring's guide?

Comment: You should file it as a bug with spring so they can figure out whether or not its a true bug.

Comment: Indeed, looks like a bug. Please, open an issue for that: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-centralized-configuration/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

Issue opened on spring's Github [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-centralized-configuration/issues/4).